# HTML injection using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to insert a label called "octosplit-label" right under the current octosplit-label.

How do I do this in Javascript?

I had an attempt that didn't work here

```
function addOneCheckbox($label) {
  $('#issues-container .table-list').append($label);
}
```

Comment: Please post code, not images of code. How is anyone supposed to read that? What is `$label`?

Comment: @carlosHT: Just a note for that edit: I would have included a link to the original image when copying the code out of it, so that if something important was in the image that wasn't copied, the original is available.  It's not critical but it is a good practice.

Comment: @Pokechu22 Noted, good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your function like this:

```
function addOneCheckbox($label) {
  $('#octosplit-label').after($label);
}
```

Remember that IDs should be unique, so the HTML contained within `$label` should **not** have the same ID (which is `octosplit-label`) and also there should be **no other labels** currently on the page with that same ID.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you (from [jQuery documents](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/):

```
function addOneCheckbox($label) {
  $($label).insertAfter('#octosplit-label');
}
```

The $label needs to be all of the html for the label.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that IDs have to be unique; therefore you cannot give the new `label` the same ID as the existing one:

```
$('#octosplit-label').after( $('<label/>',{'id':'some_id','for':'if_so_desired'}) );
```

**Reference:**

[**jQuery.after() API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Answer (score 0):

You should add some validation before try to modifying the DOM.

```
function addOneCheckbox(label) {
  var element = $('#issuelist').find('#octosplit-label');

  if(element.length > 0) {
    element.append(label);
  }
}
```